# How to do Minitab's factor analysis in R?

Tags: r, pca, factor-analysis, minitab

I am used to running multivariate factor analysis in Minitab with the default settings (method of extraction: principal components; type of rotation: none; matrix to factor: correlation; source of matrix: compute from variables; loadings for initial solution: compute from variables).

I would like to replicate this process in R. I tried using both factAnal() and prcomp(), but didn't get back the same factor loadings that Minitab returned. Does anyone know what arguments (for either factAnal() or prcomp()) would be needed to replicate this?

Comment: I have no idea what Minitab does, but there are two main ways to compute PCA. `prcomp` is one way.  the other is implemented in `princomp` Take a look at this [Cross-Validated post ](https://stats.stackexchange.com/q/20101/141956) for a discussion of the difference.

Comment: Hi. You should read up on how to ask a [good question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example).